# Simplify SQL select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table with such structure

```
CREATE TABLE UsersHistory
(
    Id          INT IDENTITY,
    UserID      INT,
    StatusId    INT,
    CreateTime  DATETIME,
    ChangedTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO UsersHistory(UserID, StatusId, CreateTime, ChangedTime)
SELECT 1,1,'20150414','20150414' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,'20150414','20150415' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,'20150414','20150416' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'20150413','20150413' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3,'20150413','20150416'
```

and query

```
;WITH k AS (
SELECT uh.UserID,MAX(uh.ChangedTime) AS Dt FROM UsersHistory AS uh
WHERE uh.ChangedTime<'20150416'
GROUP BY uh.UserID
)
SELECT k.UserID,uh.StatusId FROM k
INNER JOIN UsersHistory AS uh
    ON k.UserID = uh.UserID AND k.Dt = uh.ChangedTime
```

Query is too easy and not needs more explanation. I want to simplify my it. (Remove join with datetime type column).

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION` to achieve this. Something like this

```
;WITH CTE as 
( 
    SELECT UserID, StatusId, CreateTime, ChangedTime,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ChangedTime DESC) r
    FROM UsersHistory
    WHERE ChangedTime < '20150416'
)
SELECT UserID, StatusId FROM CTE
WHERE r = 1
```

Comment: This is of course the winner. Unnesessarily complicated questions lead sometimes to unnesessarily complicated answers. It is a good talent to see simplicity in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `first_value()`:

```
SELECT uh.UserID,
       FIRST_VALUE(uh.StatusId) OVER (PARTITION BY uh.UserId ORDER BY ChangedTIme DESC)
       MAX(uh.ChangedTime) AS Dt
FROM UsersHistory AS uh
WHERE uh.ChangedTime < '20150416';
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to select the UserId and StatusId of the records with the maximum ChangedTime where ChangedTime is not equal to '20150416'. Please, try this query:

```
SELECT
    uh.UserId, uh.StatusId
    FROM UsersHistory AS uh
    WHERE uh.ChangedTime<'20150416'
    AND uh.ChangedTime=(SELECT MAX(ChangedTime) FROM UsersHistory
                                           WHERE UserId=uh.UserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add subquery in WHERE clause. Something like that:

```
SELECT uh.UserID,
       MAX(uh.ChangedTime) AS Dt,
       uh.StatusId 
FROM UsersHistory uh
WHERE uh.ChangedTime < '20150416' 
      AND uh.ChangedTime= 
                       (
                        SELECT MAX(ChangedTime) 
                        FROM UsersHistory
                        WHERE UserId=uh.UserId
                       ) 
GROUP BY uh.UserID, uh.StatusId
```

Comment: You are grouping by userid and you select statusid whitout aggregation. It is syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

With `APPLY`:

```
Select uh1.UserID, oa.StatusID
From UserHistory uh1
Cross Apply(Select * From (Select Top 1 uh2.StatusID, uh2.Changetime 
            From UserHistory uh2 
            Where uh2.UserID = uh1.UserID And uh2.Changetime < '20150416'
            Order By uh2.Changetime desc) t where t.Changetime = uh1.Changetime) oa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    distinct uh.UserID,
    statusid 
FROM UsersHistory uh 
inner join 
    (select 
         UserID,
         max(ChangedTime) dt 
     from UsersHistory 
     group by UserID) ct 
on (ct.UserID=uh.userid and ct.dt=uh.ChangedTime)
```